# How to get annotation like support when my service layer is in another module?

Tags: java, spring, maven

My spring mvc application is broken into modules.

My services are in their own module.

Previously I used to put a @Service annotation on my services, but since they are in a seperate module, that doesn't have spring, how can I wire them up automatically like before in my web application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you split application into modules you have split its dependencies too.

For example:

Your ui depends on spring-mvc.
Your services depend on spring-core and hibernate-annotation.
Your services-impl depend on hibernate-core.

And then if your modeles have appropriate dependence. You can use @Service as you used.

Comment: I see, that doesn't seem right to me, why do I need spring-core for my services when all I need is to add the annotation..is there another way?

Comment: You can use xml configuration, and spring-core dependency move to your web module.

Comment: what about if I use a different injection framework, can I do that? like javax.inject?

Comment: Javax.inject is just specification and you have to chose implementation (spring, google guice etc.) You can switch to another later, but this specification doesn't support all features of specific provider.

Answer (score 1):

Please bear in mind that when you create WAR with your application, all required modules will be placed in `WEB-INF/lib` along with Spring dependencies (required by MVC module). 
So module in which your services are placed may have dependency to spring-context (containing annotations) since the MVC module requires this dependency itself so it will be placed in the final package anyway. If you use maven, it will handle everything under the hood automatically.

However, if you don't want to have dependencies to spring, because, for example, your 'services module' is deployed as a separate, spring-free bundle, you can use JSR330 `@Inject`, `@Resource` and `@Qualifier` Java annotations - these works interchangeable to Spring equivalents. However I don't know Java equivalents of `@Service`, `@Component` or `@Repository`, so in these cases you can rely on XML Spring context configuration in your MVC module.